# is there a way to compile the return value of some function into a regex in a single statement?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to build a regex which matches any key in a given hash. This can easily achieved via

```
my $string = join('|', keys %hash);
my $regex = qr/$string/;
```

where `%hash` is the hash in question. Out of curiosity: Is there a way to circumvent introducing the dummy variable `$string` and directly compile the return value of an arbitrary function into a regex (other than defining a custom sub or prototype)? Formulated differently: Does `qr` also have a functional form (like `readpipe` for `qx`)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the functional form of `qx`? Also, unless you know how the keys look, you should also `map quotemeta` and maybe sort by length desc (to avoid the shorter matching where the longer would match).

Comment: Also, the second line is usually written as `qr/\A(?:$string)\z/`.

Comment: @chordoba The functional form of `qx` is `readpipe`, see [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readpipe.html). Quotemeta and sorting is not necessary in my case the keys and the string I'm matching against are all three characters long (but in general your comment of course applies).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can interpolate arbitrary code into any double-quotish construct (qq, qr, qx).
`$foo` interpolates a scalar variable.  `${ code-returing-a-scalar-reference }` interpolates arbitrary code.  So to avoid the dummy variable, you do:

```
my $regex = qr/${ \join('|', keys %hash) }/;
```

But as mentioned in comment, if you want to match only string equal to one of the keys, you want to add `\A` (or `^`) and `\z` anchors.  Otherwise you will match any string containing one of the keys.

If your keys may contain regex metacharacters, you also want to quote them, like:

```
my $regex = qr/\A(?:${ \join('|', map quotemeta, sort keys %hash) })\z/;
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that there had to be something like this!

Answer (score 2):

With some warnings one *can* make that using the `(??{ code })` [extended pattern](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

sub form_patt { return '[0-9]+' }

my $re = qr/ [a-z] (??{ form_patt() }) /x; 
#say $re;

my $v = q(z23 b71);
my @m = $v =~ /($re)/g; 
say "@m";
```

The construct allows any Perl code to run inside of a pattern, and the return value of that code

> is treated as a pattern, compiled if it's a string (or used as-is if its a `qr//` object), then matched as if it were inserted instead of this construct.

So we get to generate a (sub)pattern by running code inside the regex itself (needn't be in `qr`).

The downside then is that it may well [be evaluated](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Embedded-Code-Execution-Frequency) every time it is used (even if in a variable with a `qr` object). Also, this is a complex feature; please do see documentation.

---

That regex needs adjustments, as discussed; at least so to escape the *ASCII non-"word" characters* with [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html). Most likely the patterns should be bound (anchored) as well.

If the keys come in a longer string (a broader requirement than the one in ysth's answer) then anchor the pattern by the *word boundary `\b`*, so that searching for `key` does not match `keys`

```
'\b(?:' . join('|', map { quotemeta } keys %hash) . ')\b'
```

This is one possibility, depending on the exact requirements which haven't been given.

Comment: That performs the interpolation and thus the compilation each time `(??{...})` is evaluated (once for each pass of /g). This is worse than `$re = "[a-z]".form_patt();` (which will usually only compile the pattern once, even if the match is in a loop)

Comment: @ikegami Absolutely agree. Given as a way to do it inside of a regex.

Answer (score 2):

If the keys are strings to match literally rather than regex patterns, you should be using the following to fix a code injection bug:

```
join '|', map quotemeta, keys %hash
```

On to your question, you can use either of the following:

```
my ($re) = map qr/$_/, EXPR;

my $re = ( map qr/$_/, EXPR )[0];
```

So, you'd use

```
my ($re) = map qr/$_/, join '|', map quotemeta, keys %hash;

my $re = ( map qr/$_/, join '|', map quotemeta, keys %hash )[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative, so the point here is to put some output into `$_` and then call `qr`. Therefore, I guess `my $re; $re = qr/$_/ for EXPR` should also work and is completely general. but then again these are two statements, so your `my ($re) = map qr/$_/, EXPR` is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to form the pattern by yourself. Remember that long line of alternations can make a very inefficient regex, especially if the keys have common prefixes.

[Regex::Assemble](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/Regex::Assemble) can take a list of patterns and make an efficient alternation.

use Regexp::Assemble;

```
use Regexp::Assemble;

my %hash = map { $_, 1 } qw(cat concat bird dog doge . [ | );

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
$ra->add( map { quotemeta } keys %hash );

print $ra;
```

And here's its regex:

```
(?^:(?:[.[]|(?:con)?cat|doge?|bird|\|))
```

Comment: unless it is a very long list, or has (intentional) regex metacharacters, perl will internally do a much better job than Regexp::Assemble